# Custom heuristic on pgrouting pgr_astar function

Tags: a-star, pgrouting

So i'm using pgrouting to compute shortest path on transit network, The cost of my graph is time, but the graph isn't "time dependent" - which means my arcs are available at every hour everyday,  the cost is not the distance between station but the time it take to move from one point to another.
I figured by doing the computation that pgr_astar (and even pgr_bdAstar) is slower than pgr_dijkstra. I thought it might be a heuristic problem. My questions is :

Is there a way to edit pgr_astar to insert your own heuristi

Comment: This is not a graph question.  Please red the tag descriptions.

Comment: Was your edges query ok, providing valid `x` and `y` coordinates to the function? Can you elaborate on the samples and methods you used to test A* vs Dijkstra, where you found A* losing? This sounds like a good scenario for A* to win, so it's a bit unexpected to see the opposite

Answer (score 0):

It's open-source, so yes you can, as long as you don't mind some C/C++: [here](https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/blob/main/include/astar/astar.hpp#L71). Still, what you likely want is one of the [6 built-in options](https://docs.pgrouting.org/latest/en/pgr_aStar.html#astar-optional-parameters):

```c
             switch (m_heuristic) {
                 case 0:
                     current = 0;
                     break;
                 case 1:
                     current = std::fabs((std::max)(dx, dy)) * m_factor;
                     break;
                 case 2:
                     current = std::fabs((std::min)(dx, dy)) * m_factor;
                     break;
                 case 3:
                     current = (dx * dx + dy * dy) * m_factor * m_factor;
                     break;
                 case 4:
                     current = std::sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) * m_factor;
                     break;
                 case 5:
                     current = (std::fabs(dx) + std::fabs(dy)) * m_factor;
                     break;
                 default:
                     current = 0;
             }
```

All of which are fairly simple as it is.